# How to success: function(msg) work

Tags: jquery

Here I am using below code

```
 var sData = "type=Operations&m=Employees_Employees&action=AddRecord" + "&ec=" + encodeURIComponent(_ec) + "&ed=" + encodeURIComponent(_ed) + "&d=" + encodeURIComponent(_d) + "&ys=" + encodeURIComponent(_ys) + "&tl=" + encodeURIComponent(_tl) + "&ms=" + encodeURIComponent(_ms) + "&ex=" + encodeURIComponent(_ex) + "&pn=" + encodeURIComponent(_pn) + "&mn=" + encodeURIComponent(($("#mn").prop("checked") == true) ? 1 : 0) + "&uid=" + encodeURIComponent(_uid) + "&pwd=" + encodeURIComponent(_pwd) + "&e=" + encodeURIComponent(_e) + "&mrs=" + encodeURIComponent(($("#mrs").prop("checked") == true) ? 1 : 0) + "&ne=" + encodeURIComponent(($("#ne").prop("checked") == true) ? 1 : 0) + "&sal=" + encodeURIComponent(_sal) + "&n=" + encodeURIComponent(_n) + "&fn=" + encodeURIComponent(_fn) + "&dob=" + encodeURIComponent(_dob) + "&gnd=" + encodeURIComponent(_gnd) + "&bg=" + encodeURIComponent(_bg) + "&nat=" + encodeURIComponent(_nat) + "&ejd=" + encodeURIComponent(_ejd) + "&padd=" + encodeURIComponent(_padd) + "&c=" + encodeURIComponent(_c) + "&st=" + encodeURIComponent(_st) + "&zc=" + encodeURIComponent(_zc) + "&ct=" + encodeURIComponent(_ct) + "&padd=" + encodeURIComponent(_padd) + "&pc=" + encodeURIComponent(_pc) + "&pst=" + encodeURIComponent(_pst) + "&pzc=" + encodeURIComponent(_pzc) + "&pct=" + encodeURIComponent(_pct) + "&ph=" + encodeURIComponent(_ph) + "&mob=" + encodeURIComponent(_mob) + "&ecn=" + encodeURIComponent(_ecn) + "&ephoto=" + encodeURIComponent(_ephoto) + "&note=" + encodeURIComponent(_note);
 //var sData= '123';
 //alert(sData);
 $("#imgAddNewRecord").show();
 $("#btnAddRecord").prop("disabled", true);
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "grid/",
     data: sData,
     success: function (msg) {
         alert(url);
         aTemp = msg.split("|");
         alert(aTemp);
         //print(aTemp);
         if (aTemp[0] == "FAIL") { //alert(aTemp);
             $("#imgAddNewRecord").hide();
             $("#btnAddRecord").prop("disabled", false);
             $('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: jQuery('#WebHRMain').offset().top
             }, 'slow');
             $("#divMessage").html(Message("1|" + aTemp[2]));
             $("#divMessage").slideDown(800);
         } else if (aTemp[0] == "SUCCESS") {
             //alert(aTemp[0]);
             AjaxPage("grid/?type=Details&m=" + aTemp[2] + "&err=" + aTemp[1] + "&id=" + aTemp[3], "divContainerMain");
             alert(aTemp[2]);
             alert(aTemp[1]);
             alert(aTemp[3]);
         }
     }
 });
 return (false);
 }
```

I confuse what will be "msg" parameter's value in above code.

Comment: Lots of jquery, but I don't see any `php` so why tag as php?

Comment: `msg` will be the responseText as returned from the endpoint you called in the request. Depending on the datatype returned, it may be parsed by jQuery for you (as in the case of JSON). I would suggest you read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax for more information

Comment: When in doubt: `console.log(msg)`

Comment: In the other end i am inserting data into database as follow...$result = $user_obj->addRecords($eId, $eCat, $eDesign, $eDepartment, $ePwd, $empEmail, $eNotifie, $eName, $eFname, $empMstatus, $eDob,$eBgroup, $eGn, $eN, $eJd, $exp, $ems, $eys, $eTl, $eMan, $ePan, $eAdd, $ePhone, $eCn, $eNote, $rdate);
  
      return $result;

Comment: but after inserting data the success : function(msg) is not working

Comment: still I am unable to understand, what 'msg' contains after inserting data into database

Answer (score 0):

msg will be the response data which is the outcome of your post request here.